# Need help with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, field-update

Trying to update child records based on master record status.
Consider X as a master object and Y as Child object, when X object record status is 'Complete' status of child records need to be updated to 'In progress' Status.

Comment: I have tried creating Process Builder on Master object selecting criteria as every time it is edited and status equals to Complete.

Comment: so what is the issue which you are facing?

Comment: status of child records needs to be updated when master record status is complete but it wasn't working.@Nitin

Comment: can you check the debug log whether that process builder was running or not , and also could you paste some screen shots of the process builder which you have created

Comment: I have checked Logs process builder is not running

Comment: have you activated the process builder?

Comment: I have been using Approval Process to update master record status on Approval. Does this affect process builder @Nitin

Comment: Yes I have activated It.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34528/discussion-between-nitin-and-venky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create an approval process and create a field update action, we have a checkbox :
[image]

If we need to run a process builder or workflow rule after this field update has, as in **this questions case** been made we need to make sure this checkbox is checked.

Comment: how is this a solution?